# Can my database LDF and MDF files go into this directory?

Tags: sql-server, automation, database-create

Is there a way to determine, given a drive and a directory, if a `CREATE DATABASE` command would succeed? There are basically two questions here.

1. How do you determine if a simple command like this will succeed? Which directories will contain the mdf and ldf files, and can this be determined via query (say for a tool that creates databases and needs to provide a default directory that the user can choose to use)?

   ```sql
   CREATE DATABASE v1rds
       ON PRIMARY (NAME=N'v1rds'     , FILENAME=N'v1rds.mdf')
       LOG ON     (NAME=N'v1rds_log' , FILENAME=N'v1rds_log.ldf')
   ```
2. If the user is allowed to enter a directory path into the database-creation tool, how can the directory path be validated? The command like this works in SQL Server but not in AWS RDS SQL Server:

   ```sql
   SELECT FILE_EXISTS, FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY, PARENT_DIRECTORY_EXISTS
       FROM SYS.DM_OS_FILE_EXISTS('L:\LDF');
   /****
   Error message on AWS RDS SQL Server is:
       Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
       The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'dm_os_file_exists', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

       Completion time: 2024-02-20T14:29:26.6268208-05:00
   ****/
   ```

I do not know which permissions are required on the login that calls `DM_OS_FILE_EXISTS`. Short of having to run the command as RDSA, which permissions or roles have to be granted to the login to make this work?

Comment: wrap CREATE in a TRY/CATCH ....

Comment: Do you really want the users to have full control over where the database file go and what their names will be? sounds like they can use it to overwrite some important stuff. But re: your general question, i think the old adage of "if you have to check, you can't afford it" comes in hand, just ask them for a path and try your command

Comment: @siggemannen These databases are being created automatically from a template that includes the MDF and LDF file paths.  We must validate that these paths exist when the template is created.  Our users need full control over these paths, and we need these users.  Apparently AWS RDS doesn't grant select permission for `DM_OS_FILE_EXISTS` to the admin.

Comment: Could you explain why they need the paths? Why can't you just dump it in the standard catalogue

Comment: Their systems and their hard drives host the databases that our software creates for them.  It's really their decision what drives to buy and how to connect them.  They have the paths and they need to tell us which of those paths we should be using.
As for "dump[ing]" a database "in the standard catalogue," I do not know how to do that or even what the standard catalogue is, and I have not found it in a web search.  Could you point to documentation (web page) that explains what the standard catalogue feature is and how it can be used to host database files?  I would be grateful.

Comment: Oh ok, so you don't control the hardware. So, how do you handle errors during create database today? Can't you handle invalid paths in the same part of your code? Even if you succeeded in calling DM_OS_FILE_EXISTS or whatever, it might still fail due to reasons when being ran

Comment: @siggemannen In our software, a few admin users set up the file systems and then create "templates" with which other users create databases.  Each template includes the paths to directories where the data-file and log-file are created.  The admins appreciate it when templates cannot be created with invalid paths (for example, one path contains a typo).  The alternative is having possibly one hundred angry users unable to create databases because the templates have invalid paths.